# Node child process exec vs. spawn

Tags: node.js, child-process

I am asking myself what I am doing wrong when I use `spawn` instead of `exec` executing a node child process.

The exec command works perfectly:

```
child = exec(directory + '\\downloadProducts.sh ' + promObj.requestURLS + ' ' + promObj.Name);
```

while this spawn command:

```
 child = spawn(directory + '\\downloadProducts.sh ',[promObj.requestURLS,promObj.Name]);
```

fails with the following message:

```
 Error: spawn UNKNOWN
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a closer look at the docs, you may wanna use "shell" true, https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options

Comment: @Ido No, you do not want `shell: true`. The documentation (both for `exec` and for `spawn` with `shell: true`), warns that this is vulnerable to injection attacks if the input is not sanitised. Note that OP has used the array argument for `spawn`, which is appropriate for `shell: false`. As far as I can tell from the docs, the `shell` option has no other effect.

Comment: What is `promObj.requestURLS`? Because if it's a space-separated list then that would explain the problem.

Comment: `promObj.requestURLS` and `promObj.Name` are array elements. The commands are performed for each array element

Comment: I meant: Is `promObj.requestURLS` something with a space in it, like `http://www.foo.com http://www.bar.com`? Because in that case, `exec` would treat the two URLs as separate arguments to the shell, but `spawn` would treat them as one. Or maybe other characters could affect the shell in different ways... what are the values of these strings?

Comment: Also (mostly out of curiosity): You've got a `\` in the path which suggests Windows, but an executable `.sh` file which looks like not Windows. What is your operating system?

Comment: @DavidKnipe `promObj.requestURLS` looks like `S2B_MSIL1C_20180221T042809_N0206_R133_T46QCJ_20180221T073302`. So I think there are no spaces. Second Question: Yes, my operating system is Windows, but the command gets executed by a linux command line.(cause the code will run on Apache server)

Comment: No, it's all letters, numbers and underscores, so it should be fine. And what about `directory` and `promObj.Name`?

Comment: Also, my previous comment about operating systems may be more relevant than I thought. When I google "Error: spawn UNKNOWN" I get a LOT of links that mention Windows. (But this doesn't explain why `exec` works, as far as I can tell.)

Comment: shell:true solves the issue. Am I right that it is only a security issue if user input becomes a factor?

Comment: Yes, if the strings come from a trusted source then there's no security issue. If they contain certain characters then they still might accidentally mess it up somehow. For example, you have backslashes in the path, and I'm not sure what happens if the path contains `\n`, `\t`, etc. I suppose you could fix the possible backslashes issue by replacing all the backslashes with forward slashes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is the `directory` command.
You can switch the directory before executing your command with `exec`, but not with `spawn`.

Use the `cwd` parameter for setting the working directory. You can use it both with `exec` and `spawn`:

```js
 child = spawn('downloadProducts.sh ',[promObj.requestURLS,promObj.Name], { cwd: directory });
```